# Return Boolean From HTTPClient

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have an authorization service where I am attempting to check if a user exists.

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import 'rxjs/Rx'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor( private http : HttpClient) {}

    registerUser(){
        var temp = doesUserExist().subscribe(x => temp = x);
        if(temp){
            //register User logic
        }
    }

    private doesUserExist(){
        var endpoint = [myPath];
        return this.http
            .get(endpoint)
            .map(payload => payload);
    }
}
```

When I do a get on [myPath], I get the following response from the server

```
[{"SqlResponse":"0"}]
```

I keep running into issues with the map and subscribe. In the instance above, I end up logging a `Subscriber` object. I've tried various techniques found online, including

```
    private doesUserExist(){
        var endpoint = [myPath];
        return this.http
            .get(endpoint)
            .map(payload => payload.json());
    }
```

but this method just complains that json() is not found on type 'Object'. I read that the .map already converts the string to json, so you don't need this. The next thing I tried was

```
    private doesUserExist(){
        var endpoint = [myPath];
        return this.http
            .get(endpoint)
            .map(payload => payload[0]);
    }
```

but this gave the same Subscription object in my console. I read that this is an Observable, so I started trying to cast it as `Observable<boolean>`

```
    private doesUserExist() : Observable<boolean>{
        var endpoint = [myPath];
        return this.http
            .get<boolean>(endpoint)
            .map(payload => payload);
    }
```

but again, I just get a `Subscriber` object.

**EDIT**
When I try this method...

var temp;
doesUserExist().subscribe(x => {temp = x; console.log(temp); });

I still get a generic object back... how do I access that in typescript?

[image: Image of Generic Object]

Can someone point me in the right direction? I thought you could just map the result to return, but I think since I'm getting an array of JSON as a response, it may be part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
private userExists: boolean;

private doesUserExist() : Observable<boolean>{
        var endpoint = [myPath];
        return this.http
            .get(endpoint)
            .map((resp:any) => resp.SqlResponse == "1");
    }


registerUser(){

    doesUserExist().subscribe(x => 
       {console.log('User exists ',x);
        let temp = x;  
        this.userExists = x;
       });

}
```

Comment: So if I try this, it works, but temp still isn't set - I was hoping to extend this to pulling objects back as well, but having trouble there too.

Comment: I edited my code. you need to assign variables inside the subscribe block

Comment: This is super close, but I'm still getting 'undefined' for my this.userExists and my temp variable... Do I need to do something to wait for the variable to exist before I try to use it?4

Comment: In my example, `temp` in only available in the `subscribe`, and `userExists` is available globally but will only be assigned once the  `subscribe` callback code has been called